# How to add a global menu to Gnome as it was in Unity

Tags: gnome-shell

[image]
I really like the global menu with windows in Mac and Ubuntu Unity.

In Ubuntu, Gnome works like that otherwise ....

Can I somehow do the merge as in the picture so that the top bar is along with the header, as it was in Ubuntu Unity.

Voobshchem that was also as it was in Ubuntu Unity.

Maybe there is an extension for this?

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of extensions you may try. First one is [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/).

> Pixel Saver is designed to save pixel by fusing activity bar and title bar in a natural way.

But it doesn't provide any customisation options.

Second one is a new fork of Pixel Saver called [No Title Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1267/no-title-bar/). It provides options like **disabling/theming** window buttons, **whitelisting/blacklisting** applications etc.

### Update

None of the extensions I mentioned provide a *global menu*. They can be used to merge the header/title bar of maximised windows with the top panel. I believe that's what OP wanted as they originally wrote

> Can I somehow do the merge as in the picture so that the top bar is along with the header, as it was in Ubuntu Unity. (*sic*)

There is an extension called [Gnome Global Application Menu(HUD for Gnome)](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) which claims to provide a global application menu.

Comment: I changed that to global menu because that is what it is called in Ubuntu, all menus go to the top bar, even if the windows are not maximized. Pixel saver does exactly that, from what I can see but only for maximized windows? Anyway, just thought I would clarify why I changed it, your initial answer would still apply.

Comment: @MarkKirby I beg to differ. Pixel Saver doesn't provide any global menu. It fuses the activity bar (top panel) and the title bar of a maximised window and adds window control buttons (close, minimise, maximise etc.) to the activity bar. Menu bar stays [inside the application window](https://i.imgur.com/5gsSG94.png). GNOME themselves provide something called [App Menu](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/AppMenu) by default.

Comment: Even the screenshot provided by OP doesn't have an active global menu.

Answer (score 2):

I fear there is no way. The Gnome Shell Global Menu extension was an external developer effort, and he just discontinued. For good reasons I'd say.

Maybe is time to move on, as gnome-shell looks to me a lot like being back in late 2009, hopefully there is a place for Unity look and feel refugee: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/07/ubuntu-mate-17-10-alpha-2-hud-global-menu

Comment: Is not for good reasons. It's because the impossibility to support it in the default ubuntu session that now is Wayland. The extension is working on X11 and if you want to use X11 it will work.

Comment: Also is in the hands of gtk developers add a way to use it in Wayland too. They can if they want. The question is if they want. I will fixed it to work in wayland if they give me the chance. If not, user need to know the reasons of why is discontinued.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of global menu, so I haven't tried [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) personally. Doesn't it work? It claims to be compatible with GNOME shell v3.18 - v3.24.

Comment: @pomsky https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3kwLFCIWvk

Comment: @pomsky it has quite a lot of awful reviews!

Comment: @lestcape I meant that, I mean was "reasonable" due to lack of support from wayland/ubuntu.. Now Ubuntu 18.04 is going back to X11, maybe there's hope.

Comment: @Daniele  I also added support from Wayland and i implement a solution here: https://github.com/lestcape/unity-gtk-module. You need to take a time to visit the github repository again... Just take in consideration that the Wayland support is only if you install external packages. The default ubuntu solution not support Wayland.